# unable to click submit button using casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm filling a form using casperjs and getting stuck at its submission. Below is my code snippet:

```
this.then(function(){
            this.waitUntilVisible('#ajaxSignin', function(){
                this.capture("snapss.png");

                this.fill('form#ajaxSignin', {
                 'j_username' : 'testings123testings@gmail.com',
                 'j_password' : '1234rewq'
                }, true);






                 });

            });

            this.thenClick('#signin_submit');
            this.then(function(){
            this.wait(10000, function(){
             this.capture('sn8.png');   
            });    
            });
```

In the image 'sn8.png', I'm getting this: "HTTP Status 405 - Request method POST not supported".
So I infer that there is something wrong in clicking the submit button. The script works fine till form filling.(site link: 'http://www.snapdeal.com/product/haier-le22t1000-22-inches-hd/1380076?pos=0;372')

Answer (score 0):

```
this.waitUntilVisible('#ajaxSignin', function(){
            this.capture("snapss.png");

            this.fill('form#ajaxSignin', {
             'j_username' : 'testings123testings@gmail.com',
             'j_password' : '1234rewq'
            }, true); // change this to false true will sumbit the 
                      // form right after the input was set
```

You are submitting the form before you click on the #signin_submit button.